# https in default-target-url spring security

Tags: java, https, spring-security

we are using spring security into our systems and our server is using the https scheme.

However the application is running on http not https, so the server, being apache,
is the https handler. whereas the application is running on http behind a firewall.

Working code:

```
<form-login login-page="/Login.html"    
authentication-failure-url="https://www.ourapp.com/FailureLogin.jsp"  
always-use-default-target="false"  
default-target-url="https://www.ourapp.com/SuccessLogin.jsp"/>  
<form-login login-page="/Login.html" 
authentication-failure-url="https://www.ourapp.com/FailureLogin.jsp"
always-use-default-target="false"
default-target-url="https://www.ourapp.com/SuccessLogin.jsp"/>
```

Not working code:

```
<form-login login-page="/Login.html"    
authentication-failure-url="/FailureLogin.jsp"  
always-use-default-target="false"  
default-target-url="/SuccessLogin.jsp"/>  
<form-login login-page="/Login.html" 
authentication-failure-url="/FailureLogin.jsp"
always-use-default-target="false"
default-target-url="/SuccessLogin.jsp"/>
```

is there any way to mention : 
Redirect to Url ending with /SuccessLogin.jsp but using https protocol ?

For reference, question is cross posted @ [Code ranch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/482004/Spring/Application-Frameworks/https-spring-security)
PS: I can TargetUrlResolver help me in configurations ?

Answer (score 6):

use `requires-channel="https"`

```
<http>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />
</http>
```

If non standard ports in use provide `port-mappings`

```
<http>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />
  <port-mappings>
    <port-mapping http="80" https="443" />
    <port-mapping http="9080" https="9443" />
  <port-mappings>
</http>
```

Comment: Not sure how this helps. If apache is terminating SSL then the app will *always* receive requests on http, not https. Win't adding `requires-channel="https"` cause a redirect loop?